# How to send email to recipient group in PowerShell

Tags: email, powershell

Following block used to send email from PowerShell

```
Function Mailer ($emailTo) 
{ 
$message = @" 

Some stuff that is meaningful  

Thank you, 
IT Department 
Cotendo Corporation 
it@cotendo.com 
"@        

$emailFrom = "noreply@<yourdomain>.com" 
$subject="<Your Text Here>" 
$smtpserver="<your mailhost>.<yourdomain>.com" 
$smtp=new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer) 
$smtp.Send($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $message) 
}
```

Above code help me to send email from PowerShell script. I can send email to individual email like abc@xyz.com but if there is group email or AD group email recipient then i couldn't.

Please help me to send email to AD group or group email id, is special authority require or i can send by using above script also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Send-MailMessage [-To] <String[]> [-Subject] <String> [[-Body] <String> ] [[-SmtpServer] <String> ] -From <String> [-Attachments <String[]> ] [-Bcc <String[]> ] [-BodyAsHtml] [-Cc <String[]> ] [-Credential <PSCredential> ] [-DeliveryNotificationOption <DeliveryNotificationOptions> ] [-Encoding <Encoding> ] [-Port <Int32> ] [-Priority <MailPriority> ] [-UseSsl] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/434439-how-do-i-have-powershell-send-an-email-to-multiple-recipients

you can follow this link for sending multiple users a script is there